# Sending large number of emails in batches

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5, batch-processing

I read more about this and haven't found a useful solution.

I have a hosted asp.net mvc 5 web site and I need to send a daily newsletter at 12.00 AM to the registered clients. The hosting provider allows for 200 emails per hour and I have around 500 clients. So there is definitely a separation in batches.

But what is the best way so I don't crash my app, spam flag and so on? Should I use an additional thread, put it to sleep until the next hour and so on?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of scheduling should be the job of background task. Main reason is when you application idles, the worker process is dropped to conserve system resources.

You want to consider using [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or other task schedulers.

Scott Hanselman has a blog post regarding [how to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to schedule the task.

You have 2 options:

1. You can use Windows Task Scheduler.
2. You can create a windows service .

You would probably send batches of 200 then use a thread sleep for an hour and resend the next batch.

Comment: i am running my app on a hosted server, I don't have access to Windows Task Scheduler or windows service..